# Silverlight web service query

Tags: silverlight, http, soap, cross-domain, asmx

This error shows me in silverlight page

> An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI (/HML.asmx).This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent.This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details.

Answer (score 0):

1> Have you looked at the inner Exception? What does it tell you?

2> You should understand what is cross domain access and how cross domain policy could allow it: https://support.ookla.com/entries/21097566-what-is-crossdomain-xml-and-why-do-i-need-it (it is about flash, but it is true for silverlight as well)

Anyway, be more precise about what you try to do? Access an external web service? Call an https part of your website from an http part? This error could occur in a lots of case.

Comment: Thank you for replay but It's solve now